# How to differentiate between Knowledge Article Types with status=In development an status=Deployed via Apex

Tags: knowledge, articles, status

I'm trying to fetch all article types and run SOQL on them but getting an error:
    `The article type you are searching for has not been deployed`

Is there a way through SOQL or Apex through which I can get article type status? Right now there are few articles in environment whose article type status is 'In Development'

SOQL being fired 
`FIND 'direct case to verify api fix' RETURNING Solution (Id,SolutionName,LastModifiedDate,SolutionNote,CreatedById ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC), Case(Id,Subject,Description,LastModifiedDate,CreatedById ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC), LiSFIntg_stage__non_community__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC), LiSFIntg_stage__Community_Article__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC), LiSFIntg_stage__some_label__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC) LIMIT 100`

Comment: can you post your SOQL query

Comment: @SantanuBoral - added SOQL in the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How to achieve this via Apex:**

1. Use MetadataService API

MetadataService class can be downloaded from here:
https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi/blob/master/apex-mdapi/src/classes/MetadataService.cls

2. Use above class in your Apex code to know the status of required Articles.

Example:

```
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

List<String> articleList = new List<String>{'QnA__kav', 'InstallationGuide__kav'};
List<MetadataService.Metadata> custObjList = service.readMetadata('CustomObject',  articleList).getRecords();

for(MetadataService.MetaData metaData : custObjList) {
    MetadataService.CustomObject custObj = (MetadataService.CustomObject)metaData;
    system.debug('fullName--->' + custObj.fullName + ', deploymentStatus--->' + custObj.deploymentStatus);
}
```

3. Add the Remote Site Url to avoid below error:

System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/38.0

A little further detail on the endpoint url:
Endpoint url is formed by MetadataService class using below code:

```
public String endpoint_x = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/38.0';
```

Here, the endpoint url is eventually the same Salesforce instance url where MetadataService class is placed.

**Screenshots to assist further:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even though I've added remote site settings as mentioned in point #3, I'm still getting below exception
`17:24:15.205 (1631047351)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[11553]|System.CalloutException: IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint = https://lisfintg-stage.na55.visual.force.com/services/Soap/m/38.0
`
Don't understand where it's picking this URL from while URL added under remote site settings is `https://na55.salesforce.com`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Metadata API to retrieve the status.

Refer [ArticleType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_articletype.htm)

**deploymentStatus**

> A string which represents the deployment status of a custom object or field. Valid values are:

- InDevelopment
- Deployed